# Send data from putty to bluetooth HC-6 connected on Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, putty

Here's my problem. I have an Arduino Mega 2560 connected with USB on my pc (windows 7).On the arduino i have connected a bluetooth device HC-06. I upload the following the program to my arduino:

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library

SoftwareSerial Genotronex(14, 15); // RX, TX
int BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer

void setup() {
 // put your setup code here, to run once:
Genotronex.begin(9600);

 }

void loop() {

BluetoothData=Genotronex.read(); //read incoming data
Genotronex.println(BluetoothData);  //print data received from bluetooth



  delay(100);// prepare for next data ...
}
```

I successfully connect my arduino with the bluetooth. Next i use putty and connect to the bluetooth but the problem is that it prints "-1"  meaning that the incoming data to the bluetooth is "-1" although i do not send any data from any other progamm. I also tried to send other data from putty but it didn't work. Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that to be sure that you received some data before send them to computer

```
void loop() 
{
    if (Genotronex.available())
    {
        BluetoothData=Genotronex.read();
        Genotronex.write(BluetoothData);
    }
    delay(100);
}
```

And Have you check the HC-06 configuration ? 
[Here](http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.fr/2012/06/ubuntu-hacking-hc-06-bluetooth-module.html)
and [Here](http://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/06/19/using-the-hc-06-bluetooth-module/)

Comment: After days of searching i accidentally stumbled upon a site that said that i had to connect the TXD and RXD of the bluetooth on the 10 and 11 pins of the arduino in order to receive data. I have no idea why it couldn't work otherwise.